# I need my service to run only in the background, and close immediately when app comes back to the foreground. How can I do this?

Tags: android, service

As the title suggests, I need a service that runs exclusively in the background. As you will see below, my service gets the user's location, possibly sends it to the server, and sleeps for 10 minutes at a time.

The problem I'm having is that when I try to stop the service, it doesn't do so immediately, causing the UI to be temporarily (but very noticeably) unresponsive for 30 seconds or so, depending on what the service is doing at that time.

**LocationService**

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {
    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.d("LocationService", "started");
            Hawk.init(getApplicationContext());

            listener = new Listener();

            locationsReceived = new ArrayList<Location>();

            locationManager = (LocationManager) LocationService.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

            runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                        try {
                            startLocationUpdates();
                            Thread.sleep(30 * 1000);
                            stopLocationUpdates();
                            Thread.sleep(60 * 1000);
                            if (listener.changed)
                                sendLocationUpdateWithParams();
                            else
                                Log.d("LocationService", "Location not sent to server");
                            Thread.sleep(10 * 60 * 1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            Log.e("LocationService", "Thread interrupted");
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        }
                }
            };

            mHandler.post(runnable);
        }
    });

    thread.start();

    return START_STICKY;

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    thread.interrupt();
    Log.d("LocationService", "destroyed");
}
```

**TabActivity (Primary Activity)**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
    stopService(intent);
    startingNewActivity = false; // Used to tell whether or not to start service onPause

    Log.i("TabActivity", "onResume");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
    stopService(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Start background location service
    if (!startingNewActivity) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }

    Log.i("TabActivity", "onPause");
}
```

I've done a ton of research on this and I'm pulling my hair out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can set/reset a Flag in `SharedPreferences` whenever `onPause(`) / `onDestroy()` / `onResume()` is called.Set the flag to false in `onPause()` and `onDestroy()` . Set the flag to true in `onResume()`. Check this value where you start your `Service`. If value is set, it means your app is running in foreground and start your `Service`.Else don't.

Answer (score 0):

You should set one `flag` in `onStartCommand()` method of `service` and check it in your main activity **(launcher activity)**.

If that flag returns **true** that means your service is already **started** so you can **stop it in the `onCreate()` and/or `onStart()`** method of your main activity. i.e. your service stops when app comes to foreground.

And when your app goes to **background or is closed** you should start that service again in **`onStop()` and/or `odDestroy()`** method. i.e. your service starts when app goes to background.